# Calculating the unit normal using the directional derivative

Tags: vectors

First post here so apologies if I don't follow the correct protocol.

I'm attempting to solve the following problem,

*A surface S in three dimensions is given by the equation*: $$z=h(x,y)$$

*Find the unit normal at any point on S by identifying S with an equipotential for some scalar field $\phi$ to be determined and computing $\nabla_{\phi}$.*

I started by stating that $$\phi (x,y,z) = z-h(x,y)=0$$

I intended to calculate the unit normal by saying that $$\hat n = \frac{\nabla_{\phi}}{\lvert\nabla_{\phi}\rvert}$$ but I seem to be having some trouble calculating the partial derivatives! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$\nabla \phi=(\phi_x,\phi_y,\phi_z)\implies \nabla \phi=(-h_x,-h_y,1)$ and hence $|\nabla \phi|=\sqrt{(h_x)^2+(h_y)^2+1}$.